# Measuring correlation of two time series

Tags: correlation, time-series

I have two sets of annual time series (employment growth from 2 different sources), which I display by using index. I would like to measure somehow whether series 1 (which are more timely) can be used as a proxy for predicting the direction (growth or decline) of series 2. So far I'm only presenting it graphically. I'm not sure whether measuring correlation between them is the right choice. Thanks